# How to create Azure DevOps Build/Release definitions dynamically from C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops

We can create Build/Release definitions from Azure DevOps portal, but how can we create them dynamically from C# code.

I heard about Azure DevOps Rest API's for Build/Release definitions, but still I'm confused on using it.

Could you please guide me or provide any useful links for proper implementation in c# to create Build/Release definitions dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using Azure Devops REST API  - [Definitions - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

Ther format of the request is as follows,

> POST
> [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.0)

To use the above request you can follow the sample,

```
var base64Token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{personalaccesstoken}"));
 
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Token);
 
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://{your_tfs_server}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0");
    requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"definition\": {\"id\":" + definitionId + "},\"sourceBranch\":\"$/BRANCH_NAME\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result)
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Question is about creating definition... you posted code which add defintion to build .. What do you not uderstand ... Your "answer" doesn't answers the question